# JS fadeIn & BootStrap | issue auto calculate left % margin

Tags: javascript, html, css

First, have a look there and click on the switch (Incoming/Right Now): https://ilovesubiaco.com.au/events-search/

As you can see my switch is working, but on my "Right Now" events, **my Tiles are stacking up on each other**.

The reason is that my elements.style for the main div of each (*col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 masonery_item event-now-tile*) is not calculating the left properly as it should, probably because my tiles are not displayed when my html is loaded.

I ran some test trying to remove the first "fadeOut(0)" to see if I could tweak it. 
In that case, my tiles have the right % left per element but the issue is that my tiles are still taking up white space after display none.

I also tried to reload my div with the JS ".load" but it doesn't look good so I may not know how to use it properly.

**How do I force the BootStrap library to recalculate my div Left:%; space when I switch for the first time?**

**Here is my JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $(".event-now-tile").fadeOut(0);
    $('#event-inc-now-switch').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (e, data) {
         var state=$(this).bootstrapSwitch('state');//returns true or false
         if(state){
            $(".event-now-tile").fadeOut(500);
            $(".event-inc-tile").fadeIn(500);
         }else{
            $(".event-inc-tile").fadeOut(500);
            $(".event-now-tile").fadeIn(500);
         }
     });
});
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple, replace the **position of my tile**

```
.event-now-tile{
    position:relative !important;
}
```

It's the way display is set with the fades with jQuery. Any dives which have a certain %value are stacked on each other if the display of them is set to Absolute.

I have been helped by @Davidkamer on the JS chat for this answer. Thanks to him!